# Building a Smartwatch with Esp 32 and BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-esp32, bluetooth-gatt, esp-idf

im currently working on an esp32 based smartwatch , i want to use BLE to connect to my android device and fetch the incoming notifications and display them.
i have a working android app with a foreground service that listens to notifications now i just have to forward them to esp32.

my problem is with battery life ,i want to establish a connection and then somehow put the esp32 to light sleep (or deep sleep if possible) to conserve my 400ma battery.
the goal is to have a day of battery life.

it should be something like the esp32 connecting to the device and then going to light sleep while maintaining the connection ,and when there is a new notification incoming the app will intercept it and send it the the esp that will hopefully wakeup and display the notification on the screen ,and then it goes back to sleep wile maintaining the connection.

my problem in this scenario is the sleeping and the maintaining of the connection, if you guys have any pointers or better yet any code that will be super helpful.

im using a ESP32S - WROOM-32S dev board .
please help me out.

i did try an example with normal bluetooth it works just fine but it burns threw the battery in a few hours.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'd be interested to see your code. I'm trying to do exactly the same thing.